# MongoDB getting value in subarray inside of pipeline

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am relatively new to MongoDB and currently have the pipeline that I am using to update a document, but it requires a value from a subarray inside of the document. How would I be able to get the value of price using the subarray's id to complete the operation?

```
{
  {
    ["$set"] = {
      avg = {["$add"] = {"$avg", price}}
    }
  }
}
```

I tried using `$getField` to get the price, but resulted in bad requests (probably due to improper formatting). I believe to achieve what I want would require this operator, but I am unsure of how to utilize it in the way that I need.